# What is *physical meaning*?

Tags: experimental-physics, terminology, measurements, data-analysis

What do we mean when we talk about *physical meaning* of a quantity, an equation, theory, etc.? Should the physical meaning touch on the relation between the math and the real world? Or does it have more to do with how the equation/theory is used by physicists?

**Background**
For the immediate background that prompted me to ask this question see the discussion that followed answers to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/537824/179151).

This forum contains nearly 3000 questions of the type *What is the physical meaning of X*... but do we know what we are asking?

**Opinion**
I think the question is important, because it defines the special place of physics among other disciplines. When we ask about a *physical meaning* of something we really ask how this something is related to the real world, as opposed to purely mathematical reasoning. Mathematicians and biologists do not question *mathematical* or *biological* meaning of their objects of study, since it is obvious. Yet, physicists must justify their calculations by basing them on the experimental data and making experimental predictions (as opposed to mathematicians). In the same time physicists cannot do experiments without developing complex mathematical models (unlike biologists or chemists - even though these are often more knowledgeable about complex statistical methods than an average physicist.)

Comment: I think this question is not about physics but about semantics. Besides that, the phrase can have multiple meanings depending upon context.

Comment: Is a question about what we mean when we talk about physics, a physics question? Unfortunately, I think not. This is a meta-physical (or rather, to some degree, metaphysical) question because it is about what "physics" or "physical" itself refers to. It is a fallacy that we can not answer questions of the form "What is the physical meaning of X..." without answering the question "what is 'physical meaning'." For example, in the context of a specific 'X' a question of that form likely just means something like: "What's a common example from physics where 'X' shows up? (And please discuss)."

Comment: This question could be migrated to the Physics Meta SE...

Comment: @hft physics meta is for questions concerning functioning of the community, so it would be beyond the scope. Technically, the question is really appropriate for the philosophy community, but most people there are not physicists. So I think it would be more useful and interesting here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a deep question, with important implications for understanding the mathematical form of both relativity and quantum mechanics. A quantity is a numerical quantity, and an equation expresses a relationship between quantities. The question can be largely answered by describing what is a physical quantity. As Eddington put it

- *“A physical quantity is defined by the series of operations and calculations of which it is the result.”* (Eddington A.S., 1923, The Mathematical Theory of Relativity, 2nd ed., p. 3, CUP)

This is in stark contrast to the classical idea that physical quantities exist in nature, and that the measurement merely determines their value. Eddington was writing in the context of relativity, but in quantum mechanics Dirac wrote:

- *“In the general case we cannot speak of an observable having a value for a particular state, but we can … speak of the probability of its having a specified value for the state, meaning the probability of this specified value being obtained when one makes a measurement of the observable.”* (Dirac P.A.M., 1958, Quantum Mechanics, Clarendon Press, p.47)

Again it is seen that measured quantities are the product of measurement procedures, not physical priors in the structure of matter. The mathematical theories of physics largely describe relationships found in measurement, but they go outside of that also, because we develop mathematical structures which have no direct analogue in physical reality.

Much of the misunderstanding of quantum mechanics, and indeed the belief that quantum mechanics cannot be understood, is derived from the mistaken idea that mathematics describes reality. Actually mathematics is simply language, and like other languages it can describe that which does not exist in nature. Mathematics is governed by logic. It can be used to deduce relationships found in measurements using logical arguments containing logical steps which have nothing, directly, to do with physical reality.

Comment: You touched the core of my question: I was trained in post-Soviet Russian in strictly materialist tradition which opposes *objective* reality a *subjective* constructs existing only in human minds. Thus *doing physics* means that you eventually have to relate your calculation to measurable stuff. Western education has less ideological underpinnings and students may consider the question too esoteric...

Answer (score 3):

Let me first ask you a question; what do you think I mean by 
$$\mathbf{F} = m \mathbf a$$
?

From a mathematical point of view, the equation expresses the relationship between two vectors.

However, a physicist, when using mathematics to understand nature, makes mapping between physical concepts and mathematical objects. For example for the above case, there is a measurable quantity & a physical concept called force and we are denoting it by a mathematical object, namely a vector, so the mapping is

$$\text{Force (measurable quantity)} \to \vec{F} (\text{mathematical object}).$$

Now, coming back to your question, what do they mean by "physical meaning of a mathematical expression" is the inverse mapping of the above relations, i.e

$$ \vec{F} (\text{mathematical object}) \to \text{Force (measurable quantity)}$$

Comment: Thanks. So, in your opinion, what is the physical meaning of operator $e^{-\alpha\hat{p}^2}$? - This is the question that prompted me to ask about the *physical meaning* in general.

Comment: @Vadim That is another question which I have limited knowledge.

Comment: @RogerVadim If we make some reasonable assumptions (common in *physics*) that $\hat p$ is a momentum operator for some system, and that $\alpha$ is some non-operator "constant," then the physical meaning can simply be "the exponential of the square of a momentum operator." If we further understand something like "$\alpha$ is the inverse of twice the mass times the temperature," we might further explain that $e^{-\alpha \hat p^2}$ is related to the canonical ensemble and free-particle Hamiltonian. Etc.

Comment: @RogerVadim The above explanation of what $e^{{-\alpha}\hat p^2}$ means is much closer to "a physics question" that would be accepted on this forum than an explanation of what the above explanation means (too meta for this forum). Anyways, clearly I *like* the question since I keep chasing it in the comments, but just based on "the rules" it seems like it doesn't belong as an explicit question on this forum regardless of how interesting it is. That being said, I'm fine either way.

Answer (score 2):

I understand *physical meaning* as *setting the context*.

We can learn a lot about the maths of 2-spin particles, operators, probabilities and expected values for example. But without learning about Zeeman effect and Stern-Gerlach experiment, all the stuff seems coming from nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

Many times *physical meaning* is just a sentence we use to cover our lack of a better mathematical understanding. However even in math one can ask about the *deeper meaning* of a certain result. So in some situation it's definitely a legitimate question.

I will answer by giving you an example. Let's suppose that we want to describe a quantum mechanical point particle with one degree of freedom (living on the real line). A mathematician that studied functional analysis will tell you that a state is an element of the Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. This is perfectly correct.

However it all makes sense *physically*. The reason is that Born rules tells us that for a particle described by wavefunction $\psi$ the probability of finding it in the set $\Omega$ is

$$
\int_\Omega dx |\psi(x)|^2  \tag{1}
$$

Since the total probability must be one, we see that the wavefunction must be square-integrable. Moreover, since wavefuntions that differ on a set of measure zero give the same result for quantities such as  (1), we realize that a quantum state is actually not  a function but rather an equivalence class of functions that differ on set of measure zero. We just built, *physically* the mathematical space $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

It is quite astonishing that the mathematical theory of $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ spaces has been put forward independentely (by Riesz) more or less (or a little bit earlier) in the same times as quantum mechanics was being developed.