# What constitutes a physically meaningful symmetry of a Many-Body Quantum system, especially related to Symmetry-Breaking?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry, many-body

In quantum mechanics, a (unitary) symmetry is a unitary operator $U$ which commutes with the hamiltonian $H$ of the system:

$$ [U, H] = 0 $$

For instance, in the uniform Ising model with periodic boundary conditions:

$$ H = -J\sum_i\sigma_i^z\sigma_{i+1}^z $$

there is a parity symmetry $P$ and the translation $T$ symmetry (periodic boundary conditions are assumed):

$$ P = \prod_i \sigma_i^x,\quad T = \prod_k T_{k,k+1} $$

where $T_{k,k+1}$ is the exchange operator of two neighbouring spins. Indeed, this model also has an extensive amount of unitary symmetries, since spin-$1/2$ operators are both hermitian and unitary and are conserved quantities of the system:

$$ [\sigma_i^z,H] = 0,\;\forall i $$

In general, starting from the spectrum of $H$, one can construct "infinite" unitary symmetries of the system, by linear combination of the projectors times a phase:

$$ H|\psi_{\alpha,\nu}\rangle = E_{\alpha,\nu}|\psi_{\alpha,\nu}\rangle \rightarrow 
\begin{cases}
U = \sum_{\alpha,\nu} e^{i\phi_\nu} |\psi_{\alpha,\nu}\rangle\langle\psi_{\alpha,\nu} | \\
[U,H] = 0
\end{cases} $$

where the spectrum of $H$ has been divided into sets labelled by an index $\nu$.

Is there some sense in which it is meaningful to consider only certain symmetries and not others? The only one I can think of is that $U$ is a local unitary operator, i.e. it can be written as the evolution operator a local hermitian operator $V = \sum_i V_i$ (where $V_i$ acts only on some finite region of the system and not all $V_i$ are the identity):

$$ U = e^{-i\sum_i V_i} = \prod_i e^{-i V_i} $$

For instance, this is the case for the parity symmetry and translation symmetry of the Ising chain, but not for $\sigma_i^z$.

There is also the problem of "equivalent" symmetries. For instance, there is a sense in which the two following symmetries are both parity symmetries of the Ising model:

$$ P = \prod_i\sigma_i^x,\quad P' = \prod_i\sigma_i^y $$

since they both flip the spins along the $z$ direction.

I'm asking this question because, for instance, in many-body systems, one is often interested in "perturbations which preserve the symmetry". Of course, one is not interested in perturbations which conserve *every* symmetry of $H$ (by the definition above), but rather the "physically meaningful" symmetries. Is there some sense which allows one to identify such symmetries and "equivalent" formulations, especially for many-body quantum systems?

Furthermore, it is particularly important in Landau's symmetry breaking paradigm of phase transitions, which says that spontaneous symmetry breaking is always accompanied by a phase transition.

Therefore, another, possibly more precise statement of my question, although somewhat different, is: what are the symmetries whose "spontaneous breaking" lead to a phase transition?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is \*physical meaning\*?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/538350/what-is-physical-meaning)

Comment: No, because I know there is an answer, which is probably related with locality (as mentioned in my answer), that will answer my question. Although the vagueness of my title might not attract the people who know such an answer. There is clear irrelevance to certain symmetries and clear relevance for others, I want to know if there is a general criterion for distinguishing the two.

Comment: If you really want to be precise, a possible re-statement is the following: for which symmetries is spontaneous symmetry breaking an important concept?

Comment: It is the physical problem addressed that makes certain symmetries relevant - e.g., when one studies a phase transition, one is mostly interested in the symmetry that is broken in this transition; just like there are symmetries that are relevant when looking for eigenstates or when classifying radiative transitions in atoms/molecules (typical textbook stuff.)

Comment: I understand that's how it usually works when looking at a specific model. We choose it such that it describes what we are trying to find. But I want to know why it works. If we start with a model, we find infinite symmetries which a priori are all equivalent, how come we are able to say that only certain ones will be relevant (at least within spontaneous symmetry breaking)? Namely, parity symmetry implies spontaneous symmetry breaking in the ground state of the Ising model, could we have known that a priori, without an "educated guess"?

Comment: Conceptually, the relevant symmetry should be motivated by the physics of your system (i.e., terms which break the symmetry are forbidden, or at least very small), and *then* you want to study what physical properties are meaningful, *given* that symmetry (e.g., which types of phase transitions appear, how can you identify phases, etc.). The other way round, you can pick any symmetry -- though, of course, there are some which are physically more well-motivated, see above. But this does not preclude you from studying the system subject to other symmetries.

Comment: What do you mean by "see above"? Do you mean the previous comment? I think that only provides a partial answer, as in: we know certain symmetries are relevant and so we study them. But I think that "relevant" in this case is just: by studying certain properties theoretically and experimentally, we found "this" symmetry to be important (because the properties we found respect/break this symmetry in a certain regime). What I want know is, what notions (which are not "this property is interesting") do you need to say that a symmetry results in, say, a phase transition.

Comment: For instance, I'd imagine the symmetry which gives $+1$ on a random eigenstate and $-1$ on all others not to be relevant. Or do you mean that a physical meaning can be found for this (albeit strange or very fine-tuned) symmetry? If so, which one? Specifically, can it result in a phase transition (at least in principle)?

Comment: Another way to state the question might also be this: is there some (any) general criterion which has been found to be useful in determining which symmetries are useful and which are not, especially in the context of spontaneous symmetry breaking? Doesn't have to be absolutely characterize all symmetries, but at least provide some starting point which allows us to distinguish the parity symmetry, translation symmetry and single spin "symmetry" in the Ising model. Other examples are also welcome.

Comment: By "see above" I meant the first part of my comment ("motivated by the physics of your system"). -- Let me repeat that point: Spin rotation symmetry (SO(3)) is important since interactions are often rotationally invariant. If you shield your system well from external fields, then you naturally realize systems with said symmetry. --- Put conversely: if you see a phase transition because you impose some symmetry which is *not* well preserved in your system, this is probably a fine-tuned point and the physics you see (e.g. the very fact that there is a transition) is not something ...

Comment: ... you expect to be well preserved in a real system.

Comment: And no, I don't think there is an exhaustive list of symmetries which are "useful" or not. In the context of exotic quantum phases, people also come up with various exotic symmetries which they study, and which are not necessarily symmetries one would consider particularly realistic. Yet, it can be interesting to study them, and it can yield interesting results!

Comment: What I'm looking for is exactly something that goes beyond "it depends on what you're studying". This process gives us a list made of all the symmetries we have found to be interesting. I'm not asking however for this list, but rather a criterion, which can be satisfied by this list and that we can also use as guide to find new symmetries which might be lead to phase transitions/symmetry breaking (and that we can preserve sufficiently well, though we didn't know that before). Hopefully, this criterion could even be checked numerically in some way, so that we can simply test all symmetries.

Comment: It could even apply just to spin-1/2 chains. That would already be a great starting point for more complicated systems (higher dimensions, more degrees of freedom). Is this request so unreasonable that it has to be classified as "philosophy"? (As the first comment suggested)

Comment: It's not philosophy, but I don't think it is very reasonable to hope for this. Some 20 years ago, people would have ruled out anything which is not SSB. Now there's more phases, and people might consider more symmetries to be reasonable. So I don't think this is a question which can be succinctly answered, and I would argue it is because this is the wrong mindset. (A better mindset seems to be: I have a symmetry, can something interesting happen to general systems with that given symmetry?)

Comment: Fair enough, I guess maybe there's no answer after all. The mindset you describe in your comment has been my usual mindset (indeed, I've been working on time crystals, which tries to answer exactly that question for time translation symmetry), but I was wondering whether there was some answer which says something "more". I'll still leave the question up and see if someone else can share a different perspective. Thanks anyway.

Comment: To answer one part of your question, the two parity symmetries you write down are related to each other by the 'U(1)' symmetry of the model, $\sum_i \sigma^z_i$, so they are not actually distinct symmetries.

Comment: A clue that the symmetry constructed using the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian is not a 'useful' symmetry is that it is a very high-weight (typically extensive) operator. Expressing $|\psi_{\alpha,\nu}\rangle\langle\psi_{\alpha,\nu}$ as a product of Pauli operators would be a nightmare! Granted parity is also an extensive operator, but it can be constructed by exponentiating a weight-1 operator ($\sum_i \sigma^x_i$). However these are just observations. I also don't know general criteria for when a symmetry implies a phase transition.