# Observables commuting with the Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, conservation-laws, hamiltonian, commutator, observables

Why is it that observables which commute with the Hamiltonian are constants of the motion? I can't understand why that should be true.

Comment: I want to understand the physical significance. I know the mathematics.

Comment: OK... in that case, does *this* answer your question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/538350/what-is-physical-meaning

Comment: I'll try to rephrase my question. Look if an operator commutes with Hamiltonian then it's a constant of motion. Is it because the baskets of operator are energy eigenkets and energy eigenkets don't change with time for time independent Hamiltonian or is there any other reason?

Comment: What? What do you mean "baskets"? You have received two answers that explain and answer the question you have written. You seem to be modifying your question in the comments, which is not useful or helpful for others who search based on question titles and body. If you have a different, more nuanced, question, consider posting it as a new question.

Answer (score 3):

The time evolution of an operator $O$ in the [Heisenberg picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_picture) is given by

$$
\dot O(t) = i [H,O(t)]
$$
and therefore if the operator commutes with $H$ we get $\dot O(t) = 0$, AKA it is a constant of motion.

Comment: This is true when there is no explicit time dependence. Where this is explicit time dependence in the operator (e.g., $\hat O(t) = \alpha\sin(\omega_0 t)\vec\epsilon\cdot\hat {\vec r}$) you also have a $\frac{\partial O}{\partial t}$ term on the RHS.

Comment: True, but then the definition of constant of motion would be a stretch!

Comment: Sure, but that is not what you wrote. You wrote "The time evolution of an operator $O$ in the Heisenberg picture... $\dot O = i[H,O]$." But the equation you wrote is only for operators without explicit time dependence. This is worth stating in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You got already two fine answers using the Heisenberg picture.
But it may be more intuitive (at least in my opinion)
to use the [Schrödinger picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_picture) for answering your question.

Then you have the [time-dependent Schrödinger equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation#Time-dependent_equation) for the time evolution
of a state $|\Psi(t)\rangle$
$$\frac{d|\Psi(t)\rangle}{dt}=-\frac{i}{\hbar}H|\Psi(t)\rangle$$
and, equivalently, the adjoint of this equation (using $H^\dagger=H$)
$$\frac{d\langle\Psi(t)|}{dt}=\frac{i}{\hbar}\langle\Psi(t)|H$$

Now let's examine how the expectation value $\langle O \rangle$
of an observable $O$ changes over time.
$$\begin{align}
\frac{d\langle O \rangle}{dt}
&=\frac{d\langle\Psi(t)|O|\Psi(t)\rangle}{dt} \\
&=\frac{d\langle\Psi(t)|}{dt}O|\Psi(t)\rangle
 +\langle\Psi(t)|O\frac{d|\Psi(t)\rangle}{dt} \\
&=\frac{i}{\hbar}\langle\Psi(t)|HO|\Psi(t)\rangle
 -\frac{i}{\hbar}\langle\Psi(t)|OH|\Psi(t)\rangle \\
&=\frac{i}{\hbar}\langle\Psi(t)| \underbrace{(HO-OH)}_{=0}|\Psi(t)\rangle \\
&=0
\end{align}$$

That means the observable $O$ is a constant of motion.
The important step above was the last one,
where we used that $O$ commutes with the Hamiltonian $H$.

Answer (score 1):

The Hamiltonian gives you the time evolution operator. So a general observable evolves (in the Heisenberg picture) as
$$ O(t) = e^{i H (t-t_0)} O(t_0) e^{- i H (t-t_0)} \,.$$
If $O$ and $H$ commute, you can bring the exponentials together, they cancel out and you find that $O(t)$ is the same at every time $t$.

Comment: I understand the mathematics i want to know why that should be physically true. Like what's so special about the observable that commutes with Hamiltonian that makes it constant of motion